# Java GUI - Possible to store JPanels inside a single main JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout

I am working on a semester project that I have and I was wondering if it was possible to store 3-4 JPanels instead one single "main" JPanel. The reason for me asking this is because I a trying to make a GUI checkbook program and my checkbook has 7 buttons that should open a new window once I click on it. To switch between each window I'm going to have to use the CardLayout, but my understand of the CardLayout is that I can only assign one single JPanel to that card so I can't assign multiple JPanels to a single Card layout so when the user clicks on a different card 3-4 different JPanels appear.

The reason that I am asking this is because I asked for help earlier and received help for creating my first window in this project, it produces the output I want PERFECTLY, but uses more than 1 JPanel in doing so. Since this prevents me from continuing on to the other steps of my 7 GUI Windows, I am stuck.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class checkbook extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   private static final String title = "Use The Buttons Below To Manage Transactions";

   private static final String[] bottomButtons = { "Create a New Account",
         "Load a Trans from a File", "Add New Transactions",
         "Search Transactions", "Sort Transactions",
         "View/Delete Transactions", "Backup Transaction", "Exit" };


   static JButton Button[] = new JButton[8];
   static ActionListener AL = new checkbook();

   public checkbook() {

      JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(title, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 18));
      JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
      titlePanel.add(titleLabel); // put it in a JPanel so it will expand to fill BoxLayout

      JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
      JPanel accountBalancePanel = new JPanel();
      accountBalancePanel.add(new JLabel("Account Name:"));
      accountBalancePanel.add(new JTextField(10));
      accountBalancePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(4));
      accountBalancePanel.add(new JLabel("Balance:"));
      textfield = new JTextField("0.0", 10);
      textfield.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
      accountBalancePanel.add(textfield);


      JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
      northPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(northPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      northPanel.add(titlePanel);
      northPanel.add(accountBalancePanel);

      JPanel southBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4, 1, 1));

      for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

         Button[i] = new JButton(bottomButtons[i]);
         southBtnPanel.add(Button[i]);
         Button[i].addActionListener(AL);

      }


      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 100))); // just an empty placeholder
      add(southBtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      checkbook mainPanel = new checkbook();


      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkbook");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  createAndShowGui();
               }
            });
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      if(e.getSource() == Button[7]) {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }

}
```

***Credit goes to Hovercraft Full Of Eels for showing me the above example***

If there is anything that is unclear about my question, please ask and I will do the best I can to fix it.

***Here is what the code produces***:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY0c3.png

Comment: Please clarify: `"my understand of the CardLayout is that I can only assign one single JPanel to that card so I can't assign multiple JPanels to a single Card layout so when the user clicks on a different card 3-4 different JPanels appear."` This statement confuses me greatly.

Comment: Yes of course, a couple of days ago when I went to ask my professor to clarify how I would make different windows of my checkbook program he said to use a CardLayout and when he showed me an example of it I asked him if it was possible to add Multiple JPanels to a single card(e.g. if card1 and card2 are JPanels) "contentPane.add("Card1", card1) contentPane.add("Card1", card2); contentPaneLayout.show(contentPane, "Card1")So i am adding both card1 and card2 JPanels into Card1 so when I display Card1, both JPanels appear.

Comment: As an example using the code above, I want to store northPanel and the southBtnPanel into a single Card so that when the user clicks on a button it shows all the JPanels that I've assigned to that one card. But my professor told me that we can't do that, you can only assign a single JPanel to a card.

Comment: Note: **One** panel might contain 3-4 panels.  And that **one** panel can then be a single card in a `CardLayout`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How would I do that? Because I asked my professor that same question, if I can store many JPanels into a single JPanel and he said "no only one".

Comment: Wouldn't that **One** panel be a "contentPane" or container (EX:Container contentPane;   Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();       contentPane.add(jpanel);
      contentPane.add(jpanel1);   Then my "contentPane is just my main window and i just make "contentPane2" to be my second window.

Comment: *"I asked my professor that same question, if I can store many JPanels into a single JPanel and he said "no only one"*  Your professor is a moron.  Take the first panel (`panel1`), set a layout like flow layout or grid layout.  Add three panels as `panel1.add(panel2); panel1.add(panel3); ..`

Comment: Ohhh so with the code I have I could do something like firstPanel.add(northPanel); firstPanel.add(southBtnPanel); then when using the card layout i just reference it to the firstPanel which then shows all the panels i've added to it? If that's the case then Thanks! Need to try that! Can't believe my professor said I couldn't do that!